# Can boost::asio::async_read_until detect an endless stream

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I am using boost::asio::async_read_until to read a message from a socket, using a newline as a delimiter.

e.g. boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, buffer, "\n", .....)

Everything is hunkey dorey and works fine.

Is there an alternative way to use this function, or a similar one, that can detect an endless sequence of characters that do not have a newline constant in them.

e.g. a malicious user might fire a continuous sequence of ZEROS at my server

## socat /dev/zero TCP4:localhost:55555

I can't be the first person in history to have come across this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273929/boost-async-read-until-combine-match-condition-with-limit-size-to-read

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for, then?

Comment: `endless` is subjective. You could implement such a limit yourself using a pragmatic choice of upper bound for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for this and also for the other responses. I seemed to have opened a can of worms here. We do have an internet facing app so we will need to look at using async_read_some and some sort of function object. In the meantime, I;ll use a fixed sized buffer and assume that a buffer overflow is an invalid message

Answer (score 0):

You can use version 4 of the 4 overloads:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload4.html

In your function object, which would normally be an interface to a state machine, you can count characters, detect illegal data streams or any other means necessary.

It's probably worth mentioning that if your application is running in a hostile environment (i.e. internet-facing) then you will probably want to use `async_read_some` to feed your state machine and will want a timer to catch and kill connections that sit and consume resources.

Comment: Thanks for this and also for the other responses. I seemed to have opened a can of worms here. We do have an internet facing app so we will need to look at using async_read_some and some sort of function object. In the meantime, I;ll use a fixed sized buffer and assume that a buffer overflow is an invalid message.

Comment: @PMcK the internet is about the most worm-filled can there is... :)